# Transaction unconfirmed, send with Multibit HD, too low fee

Tags: transactions, multibit, multibit-hd

2 days ago I tried to send BTC to a different address, using Multibit HD (then not knowing Multibit is dead).
It was send with a fee of 0,0001 (52.083 sat/B).
I now know this fee was too low.

The transaction is not being confirmed by the network. And after using the repair wallet in multibit a couple of times it is still saying sending. Older transactions are now saying receiving isntead of received...

I have not used BTC in a while and did not know that multibit is dead.
I am trying to google my way out of this but so far no luck.

Is there any way for me to cancel the transaction and resend it with more fee?

By the way I am not so good with software so some of the options I have come across are too risky for me.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: TX 4b0e68e0ca47f45f8adfbe749ff117ab91f871161b3c81e9a831550cf5c61899

Answer (score 0):

As you have alread realised the Bitcoin mempool is currently (since the last 7 days) full of high-fee paying transactions.

Unfortunately I do NOT expect the number of transactions paying such high fees to drop significantly during the following days/weeks. But eventually with some luck when not so many new high-fee paying transactions are broadcasted your transaction may be confirmed.

MultiBit does not support replace-by-fee (RBF) as far as I know. Therefore you cannot do much more than sit and wait. If your transaction is not confirmed within around 1-2 weeks, then the network will drop if from the mempool and you can broadcast a new transaction with a higher fee.

Comment: Ok thanks alot for your answer! When I open multibit does it rebroadcast the transaction and thus refreshing the 1-2 week reset "timer"?